# Why was the question "parameters and coding", which consisted solely of that title and an error message, deleted? 

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

I'm talking about the following question: [parameters and coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480605/parameters-and-coding/)

I answered that question properly, and received 5 up-votes for my trouble, only to see the question deleted!

I don't know what the reason for this could be... Surely there must be an alternative? Locking, perhaps?

When the effort expended answering a question can be wasted via such deletion, what purpose does it serve? How can I possibly determine which questions are worth answering?

I believe that question was correct, and merely poorly formatted and lacking all semblance of context apart from that contained in the error details and tags... However, these details alone were sufficient for me to answer!

Comment: Can you _honestly_ say that it was a proper question?

Comment: @JeffMercado -i already admitted at last OP miss the fomaating in his qestion but it doent lead to delete ....that what i think....

Comment: What question? _Look_ at it. What was the title? "parameters and coding"... What was the body of the post? Just some out-of-context error message with absolutely no code in it or actual question.  Why should it be allowed to exist?

Comment: Do you really, _honestly_ need to ask? Have you ever read the FAQ?

Comment: Simply don't waste time with "questions" like this one. If you answer it, you will sort of encourage asking this kind of "questions". Instead you should ignore it / flag it / comment on it...

Answer (score 15):

Why was the question deleted? Because it's not a useful question. In fact, it wasn't even a question at all. It was just an error log, and one without enough context to make the question answerable.

In sum, the question didn't make any sense, didn't show any evidence of research effort, and is unlikely to help anyone else ever in the future of the Internet. These types of questions are regularly closed and deleted. It keeps the signal-to-noise ratio on the site high.

For those non-10k users, the question looked like this:

> #### parameters and coding
>
> ```
> Error 28  'WindowsFormsApplication1.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition 
> for 'Parameters' and no extension method 'Parameters' accepting a first argument of 
> type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using 
> directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\cofex\Desktop\Gestion de salair - 
> pompier - ARAB - Copy - Copy\Gestion de salair - pompier - ARAB - Copy - 
> Copy\WindowsFormsApplication1\Classes\employeurclass.cs 152 26
> WindowsFormsApplication1
> ```
>
> [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

Please don't try and tell me that this question was worth keeping around.

Comment: Thanks for not forgetting us <10Ks :P

Comment: the error is descriptive .........to answer the question

Comment: **It's not even a question.**

Answer (score 12):

It's polite, upon answering a question that many others clearly do not understand (or even recognize as a question), to then edit the question such that it clearly states the problem.

Otherwise, you get what we have here.

Comment: Very very true - if you, @Pranay, managed to understand a question where no one else could, improve it so that the rest of us can understand...

Answer (score 11):

The question was deleted because

- it's not a real question (and closed as such)
- it wasn't properly written (was it even *written*, or cut and pasted from an IDE's output panel?)
- it doesn't help anybody but the OP (does it even help *the OP*?)

> I dont know reson why its happing like this on StackOverlow...rather deleting functionality on **SO why dont they proviede functionlity like Locking Question**....

We can lock questions, but we don't lock questions on the basis of being answered, especially when they are of very low quality.

> As per me question asked by OP is Correct its just not well fomatted and the just left the error detail and which good to analyse and answer....

You call *this* a "Correct" question?!

```
    Error   28  'WindowsFormsApplication1.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition 
    for 'Parameters' and no extension method 'Parameters' accepting a first argument of 
    type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using 
    directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\cofex\Desktop\Gestion de salair - 
    pompier - ARAB - Copy - Copy\Gestion de salair - pompier - ARAB - Copy - 
    Copy\WindowsFormsApplication1\Classes\employeurclass.cs 152 26
    WindowsFormsApplication1
```

If you think it could have been improved, why didn't you help out with that, then? The community was given ample time to do so (9 hours between being closed and deleted).

Comment: the error is descriptive .........to answer the question

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: @pra - the error describes the **error** it does not describe the problem.

Comment: @Lix - error describe he is missing namespace in the code file.........

Comment: Would a question containing only the error `"File not found"` be descriptive too?  Clearly a file is missing... The answer is **no** - it is not descriptive of the problem the OP is facing... The error might hint towards the problem but it does not describe it.

Comment: @PranayRana, if the error is really so useful and descriptive, then the "question" should still have been closed and deleted because it includes the _exact_ information needed to fix the problem, but the OP just couldn't be bothered to try to fix it themselves.